# How to count differences between Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA which comparing 2 cells. Each cell can contain between 1 and 3 different parameters ant parameters are trimmed by the "," comparison is made by simple double for loop(check code). Thing what i can't figure it out is that: How to modify code and get number of unique entries, example
cell 1 [music, art, science]; cell 2 [art, music]; When i run my for loops i get 2 matches(which is fine) but how to count number of unique words in this case should be 3.

I have tried to enter this part of code but its not working well **num_possible = num_possible + 1**

```
game_tags_parts = Split(Cells(11, 2), ",")
game_tags_parts_j = Split(Cells(11, j), ",")
   num_matches = 0
   num_possible = 0
For m = LBound(game_tags_parts) To UBound(game_tags_parts)
   num_possible = num_possible + 1
        For n = LBound(game_tags_parts_j) To UBound(game_tags_parts_j)
           If Trim(game_tags_parts(m)) = Trim(game_tags_parts_j(n)) Then
               num_matches = num_matches + 1
           End If
        Next n
Next m
```

Actual result should be number of unique words used in those cells, in some cases i get 3 matches, example cell 1 [scifi, space, star] cell 2 [star, space, scifi] and its in total 3 matches. Modification should provide me an number 3 as number of unique words used in both cells. Or in this case where i have cell 1 [art, music, science] and cell 2 [scifi, space, star] where program gives me 0 same words and modification should give me a number 6 as unique used words.

Comment: total_word_count - match_count  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to get a unique count is to use a Dictionary object:

```
game_tags_parts = Split(Cells(11, 2), ",")
game_tags_parts_j = Split(Cells(11, j), ",")

Dim myDict As Object
Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each v In game_tags_parts
    If Not myDict.Exists(v) Then myDict.Add v, v
Next v

For Each v In game_tags_parts_j
    If Not myDict.Exists(v) Then myDict.Add v, v
Next v

MsgBox "unique count: " & myDict.Count
```